# Cannot import a private cocoapod in developing pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am creating a private pod suppose "pod X" which have dependency on suppose "pod Y". I successfully created and it passed the validation but I cant import classes of "pod Y" in "pod X" hence I cannot write code in "pod X" using "pod Y" classes. I have added dependency correctly. If I write the import statement its gives error "No such Module". For all this purpose I am using Swift as language.

This is how my podspec file looks I have changed name and links in the following for privacy:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name = 'Pod X'
  s.version = '0.1.0'
  s.license = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.summary = 'Pod X is to handle all the network related and Models etc'

# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!

  s.description      = <<-DESC
  TODO: Pod X is to handle all the network related and Models etc.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://****/podx.git'
  s.authors = { 'MGNetworkClient_OWNER' => 'USER_EMAIL' }
  s.source = { :git => 'https://***/podx.git', :tag => s.version }
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
  s.source_files = 'Source/*.swift'
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'MGNetworkClient' => ['Resources/**/*.{png}']
  }
   s.dependency 'Pod Y'
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually this would mean you either have the name of the import wrong, or the dependency isn't added. Are you using frameworks by any chance?

Comment: I am using import correctly, I have verified that. Also dependency is added as library is visible in Example project after running "pod install" in that.

Comment: Are you sure you've **uncommented** `use_frameworks!` in your `Podfile`?

Comment: Yes It was automatically written and uncommented as I  created the pod in Swift

Comment: Could you add your `podspec` in the question?

Comment: @Dershowitz123 I have edited the Question please review

Comment: Is your example xcode project failing to build, or your xcode project that contains the **Pod X** code?